# When copy paste the Component, Component Metadata is not getting updated through Event Handle

Tags: sdl-tridion, event-system

When I am copy pasting the Component, the Component Metadata is not getting updated(cleaning the fields) through Event Handle, I am subscribing the event as shown below. but when checked the newly created component the metadata fields are not updated(cleaned). can anyone please help me on this.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, CopyEventArgs>(OnCopysubject, EventPhases.Initiated);

private void OnCopysubject(Component subject, CopyEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
        {            
            try
            {
                log.Info("ComponentMetdata.Events: " + subject.Title, LoggerCategory.General);
                
                if (subject.Metadata != null)
                {
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.LoadXml(subject.Metadata.OuterXml);

                    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("uuid", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("xmlns"));

                    var xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//uuid:metadata", nsmgr);
                    if (xmlNode != null)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNode)
                        {
                            if (node.Name != "targetMarkets")
                            {
                                node.InnerText = "";                                
                            }
                        }

                        XmlElement xElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
                        subject.Metadata = xElement;
                        log.Info("ComponentMetdata.Events: " + "subject.Metadata.OuterXml" + subject.Metadata.OuterXml, LoggerCategory.General);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                log.Info("ComponentMetdata.Events: " + exception, LoggerCategory.General);
            }
            

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

- You'd have to get the component from the `CopyEventArgs.CopiedObject`, which will have the results of the copy operation.
- The CopiedObject will be null in the `Initiated` event phase. Use the `Processed` phase instead of Initiated in the event subscription.
- You've not called the `VersionedItem.Save()` method to save the metadata changes made on the copied component.
- Rather than you processing the XML, use `ItemFields` available in the `Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields` namespace. It's much simpler to get/set the content and metadata fields of components based on their schema.

So in your case, this should work:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, CopyEventArgs>(OnCopysubject, EventPhases.Processed);
 
private void OnCopysubject(Component subject, CopyEventArgs copyEventArgs, EventPhases phase)
{
    try
    {
        Component component = (Component)copyEventArgs.CopiedObject;
        
        if (component.Metadata != null )
        {
            ItemFields metadataFields = new ItemFields(subject.Metadata, subject.MetadataSchema);

            // Based on the type of the metadata field, cast to the apppropriate class. 
            ((TextField)metadataFields["targetMarkets"]).Value = "";

            subject.Metadata = metadataFields.ToXml();
            subject.TryCheckOut();
            subject.Metadata = metadataFields.ToXml();
            subject.Save(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer and good point on working with the fields over the API!

Comment: Thank you Sabarish, this was very useful and resolved the issue.